# Determining the minimum and maximum value of a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

Let 
=|2|+|4²-3|.
How do I determine  its maximum and minimum values without using graphing calculators, desmos, etc. 
I tried to find the values of x where
 and 4²-3 changed signs but it seemed to get me nowhere.

Comment: Distinguish the $4$ possible cases depending on the sign of the expressions in absolute value

Comment: @JulioPuerta Ahh yes, Got my answer.  Thanks :)